# Joining and selecting multiple tables and creating new column names

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, insert

I have very limited experience with MySQL past standard queries, but when it comes to joins and relations between multiple tables I have a bit of an issue.

I've been tasked with creating a job that will pull a few values from a mysql database every 15 minutes but the info it needs to display is pulled from multiple tables.

I have worked with it for a while to figure out the relationships between everything for the phone system and I have discovered how I need to pull everything out but I'm trying to find the right way to create the job to do the joins.

I'm thinking of creating a new table for the info I need, with columns named as:

```
Extension | Total Talk Time | Total Calls | Outbound Calls | Inbound Calls | Missed Calls
```

I know that I need to start with the extension ID from my 'user' table and match it with 'extensionID' in my 'callSession'. There may be multiple instances of each extensionID but each instance creates a new 'UniqueCallID'.

The 'UniqueCallID' field then matches to 'UniqueCallID' in my 'CallSum' table. At that point, I just need to be able to say "For each 'uniqueCallID' that is associated with the same 'extensionID', get the sum of all instances in each column or a count of those instances".

Here is an example of what I need it to do:

```
callSession Table

UniqueCallID | extensionID |
----------------------------
A              123
B              123
C              123

callSum table

UniqueCallID | Duration | Answered | 
------------------------------------
A             10         1
B             5          1
C             15         0

newReport table

Extension | Total Talk Time | Total Calls | Missed Calls
--------------------------------------------------------
123         30                3             1
```

Hopefully that conveys my idea properly.

If I create a table to hold these values, I need to know how I would select, join and insert those things based on that diagram but I'm unable to construct the right query/statement.

Comment: Hi. Why are you saving `extensionID` in a different table?

Comment: TL; DR; See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply JOIN the two tables, and do a group by on the extensionID. Also, add formulas to summarize and gather the info.

```
SELECT 
    `extensionID` AS `Extension`,
    SUM(`Duration`) AS `Total Talk Time`,
    COUNT(DISTINCT `UniqueCallID`) as `Total Calls`,
    SUM(IF(`Answered` = 1,0,1)) AS `Missed Calls`
FROM `callSession` a
JOIN `callSum` b
    ON a.`UniqueCallID` = b.`UniqueCallID`
GROUP BY a.`extensionID`
ORDER BY a.`extensionID`
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok, quick question: In the future, if I add 2 columns like this:
 sum(if(LEGTYPE1 = #)) as Total_Outbound
    , sum(if(LegType1 = #)) as Total_Inbound

where in legtype1 I want to add all '1's as total outbound and all '2's as inbound, would I replace the pound signs with 1,2,1 and 2,1,2 respectively? I'm confused on the IF statement a bit

Comment: @TomN. If it works for you, please accept the answer. The IF function takes three arguments. A condition (evaluates to true/false), a value for TRUE, and a values for FALSE. So in your example, you replace the # sign with three things. The value the column is equal to (your test), followed by a comma and either a 1 or 0, another comma, and the opposite of the 2nd argument. IOW, if it was 1, then a 0 or vs-versa.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join and group by

```
  select 
      a.extensionID
      ,  sum(b.Duration) as Total_Talk_Time 
      , count(b.Answered) as Total_Calls
      , count(b.Answered) -sum(b.Answered) as Missed_calls
  from callSession as a 
  inner join callSum as b on a.UniqueCallID = b.UniqueCallID
  group by a.extensionID
```

Comment: Thank you that seems to be working great. Now, one quick addition/question. If I also needed to join the 'users' table and match extensionID between it and 'callsession' table but then print 'extension' from 'users' as '4-Digit Extension', would I join users as c, and then just place c.extension in the select?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick. What you are being asked to do is to aggregate the number of and duration of calls. Unless explicitly requested, you do not need to create a new table to do this. The right combination of JOINs and AGGREGATEs will get the information you need. This should be pretty straightforward... the only semi-interesting part is calculating the number of missed calls, which is accomplished here using a "CASE" statement as a conditional check on whether each call was answered or not.

Pardon my syntax... My experience is with SQL Server.

```
SELECT CS.Extension, SUM(CA.Duration) [Total Talk Time], COUNT(CS.UniqueCallID) [Total Calls], SUM(CASE CS.Answered WHEN '0' THEN SELECT 1 ELSE SELECT 0 END CASE) [Missed Calls]
FROM callSession CS
INNER JOIN callSum CA ON CA.UniqueCallID = CS.UniqueCallID
GROUP BY CS.Extension
```